# Laravel - created virtual host, however website will not connect to localhost

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, virtualhost

I am desperate for help. I am new to mac and Laravel. I have just installed a fresh project and Laravel and i am trying to create the virtual host, my code:

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot “/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs”
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot “/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/learninghub/public”
ServerName learninghub.local
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   learninghub.local
```

Getting the following error -

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If
>   you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.9
>   mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Referring to homebrew

> Error: Failure while executing; `git clone
>   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core` exited with
>   128.

Comment: 1) You cannot have a `DocumentRoot` *under* another `DocumentRoot`.  If you are starting out, keep it simple - you only need 1 vhost right now, get rid of the 2nd.`localhost` works out of the box, so just use it for now. 2) Maybe just a formatting thing, but the quotes you show around your `DocumentRoot` path are fancy curly quotes - those will not work in an Apache config file. 3) Before you try getting Laravel working, make sure Apache works - put a simple `index.html` with "hello world" get that working before moving on to Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/learninghub/public"
    ServerName learninghub.local
    ServerAlias *.learninghub.local
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/learninghub/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac, I would highly suggest using [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/valet) instead. Its a very compact development environment that uses Nginx and dnsmasq to serve your local projects with pretty URLs (`*.test`).

With Valet, you really don't have to fiddle with virtual hosts or edit your `hosts` file. You just add the directory where your projects live to Valet, and it will automagically serve them.

Comment: Hi @tamrat , thanks for this.. yes i am on mac.. i have tried to install homebrew but getting an error (i have added to my original post)